# Centre Screen using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have made a custom confirmation Dialog in JavaFX. I would like to Center this dialog on the screen, however when I try the following code it does absolutely nothing;

```
//window is the stage name
window.centerOnScreen();
```

is there any other method which I can use or am I using this code wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I usually used Java default toolkit to get screen width and height, then you use it like screen height / 2 - window height / 2 and same for width. Then your window will be positioned right in the center of the screen. Notice that your window is positioned by top left corner.

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558449/javafx-center-stage-on-screen